# Using onClick with a React Component, Clickable Component boundaries don't match visible location on the Browser

Tags: reactjs

[image]
BodyCol is a styled component div with a blue border. It is the one that envelopes the black-bordered div seen on the right. The blue highlighted area is where the onClick for the BodyCol runs when clicking space in the browser.

Comment: Why did you delete most of the question? It looked relevant. Now the question is unclear and might get closed

Comment: Thought this would be a better summary. The above explains the same issue. Do you understand what I'm trying to say with the new question?

Comment: No, not really.